# sort datatable columns basesd particular column?

Tags: c#-4.0, sorting, datatable

if my datatable like this

```
    city       area            areanumber

    chennai    choolaimedu         565

    chennai    nungambakam         323

    trichy     K.K nagar           989

    trichy     D.nagar             801

    sivakasi   firenagar           253
```

am using below code

```
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = "areanumber";
        dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = "area";
        dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = "city";
        dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

the output is like this

```
        city       area            areanumber

       chennai    choolaimedu         565

       chennai    nungambakam         323

       sivakasi   firenagar           253

       trichy     D.nagar             989

       trichy     K.K nagar           801
```

in above table area name also get sort based on city column eg:

trichy D.nagar   989

trichy K.K nagar 801

but the areanumber did'nt get sort like area

i want output like below table

```
        city       area            areanumber

       chennai    choolaimedu         323

       chennai    nungambakam         565

       sivakasi   firenagar           253

       trichy     D.nagar             801

       trichy     K.K nagar           989
```

Thanks

Comment: How in your second table sample, D.Nagar got 989 areanumber when it was having 801 in your original table? Is it what you are expecting?

Comment: bro i wana output like that ok

Comment: Hmmm. Then I feel the problem is not about Sorting. I think you will need to write the code for that and fill a new datatable to get the desired things. So If I am right, You want each column to be in sorted manner irrespective of their corresponding values in the row. Let me know if I am clear....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to sort your `DataTable` in one call:

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "city asc";
dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought you want to sort by areanumber first. Fixed and please try again.

Comment: Can you post what results you are getting using my method?

Comment: like above second table only gzaxx

Comment: @RAMARAJ.M can you please tell me if in your database the areanumber of choolaimedu is 565 then why do you want to sort it to areanumber 323 as sorting will never change corresponding coloumns ...

Comment: @SandeepChauhan is right. I totally missed that! My sorting works ok, but you can'get results you want because your numbers are switched and that is not possible.

Comment: yes sorting done by @gzaxx will work fine but it won't give you desired result as your desired results are not possible ..

Comment: hello gzaxx i want sort based city column only k

Comment: `dt.DefaultView.Sort = "city";` will do the job.

Comment: i want sort all columns based on city column only gzaxx ,

Comment: sorry but sort based on city column = sort city column, my first examples sorted by all columns but that was wrong, now I sort by city and it is wrong as well. Sorry but I just do not know what you expect.